# Maximize the button in a gridlayout

Tags: android, xml, button, maximize

I have an activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                  app:rowCount="4"
                                  app:columncount="4">

<Button
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_column="0""/>


<Button
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_column="1"/>

<Button
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_column="2"/>

<Button
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button5"

    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_column="0"/>

<Button
    android:text="5"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_column="1"/>

<Button
    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_column="2"/>
<Button
    android:text="7"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_column="0"/>
<Button
    android:text="8"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_column="1"/>

<Button
    android:text="9"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_row="2"
    app:layout_column="2"
    />
```

which looks like this:

[image: Current layout]

I would like to change the button 1, so that it would be stratched vertically and 4 and 7 must be minimized to wrap_contnet (made in photoshop)
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

More specifically, I need to make this:

[image]

I made this by using custom width, but I don't know how to make this using layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.win72.myapplication.MainActivity"
grid:columnCount="3"
grid:rowCount="3">


<TextView
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="10"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_rowSpan="2"

    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:background="#a49595"
    android:text="90"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="457dp"/>

<TextView
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="10"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="2"
    grid:layout_rowSpan="2"

    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:background="#a49595"
    android:text="90"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

<TextView
   grid:layout_row="2"
   grid:layout_column="0"
   grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
   grid:layout_columnWeight="1"

   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:text="4"
   android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

<TextView
    grid:layout_row="2"
    grid:layout_column="2"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"


    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<Button
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

<Button
    grid:layout_row="1"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:columnweight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"

    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    />
```

Comment: have u looked here ? https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Comment: use this may help full                                                              http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/using-linearlayoutmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

Using staggeredgridlayout you can achieve that.

Comment: Is it the only way? I can't make it by changing the weights or something like this?

Comment: gridview items(buttons) count is constant? or dynamically change?

Comment: If it will work only with dynamic, than I will change the layout to dynamic.

Comment: I added another layout to the question: maybe in this case it would be easier to realize?

Comment: you can use layouts and then you can achieve the same easily . Their is no  need of Gridview right?

Comment: I fixed :)
Just used rowspan

Answer (score 0):

I found that making dynamic count of rows/columns and using rowspan can make this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.win72.myapplication.MainActivity">


<TextView
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_rowSpan="3"

    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:background="#a49595"
    android:text="90"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:clickable="true"
    />

<TextView
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="2"
    grid:layout_rowSpan="3"

    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:background="#a49595"
    android:text="90"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

<TextView
   grid:layout_row="3"
   grid:layout_column="0"
   grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
   grid:layout_columnWeight="1"

   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:text="4"
   android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

<TextView
    grid:layout_row="3"
    grid:layout_column="2"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"


    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<Button
    grid:layout_row="0"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

<Button
    grid:layout_row="1"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"

    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    />
```

[image]

Thanks a let for help!